# Restrict traffic layer on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm aware that it is possible to enable traffic layer on Google maps, but it enables traffic on the entire map. Is it possible to restrict the traffic layer to specific route similar to Uber? [image]
I'm trying to achieve this in Android, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a service available with a premium client ID from Google maps:

[Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsAdvanced)

> traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) — Specifies the assumptions to use when calculating time in traffic. This setting affects the value returned in the duration_in_traffic field in the response, which contains the predicted time in traffic based on historical averages. The traffic_model parameter may only be specified for driving directions where the request includes a departure_time, and only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID.